# Java: SimpleDateFormat not formatting in desired TimeZone

Tags: java, date, datetime, formatting, timezone

I would like to format dates, for a specific time zone,  GMT, and I want the result of that formatting to be the same always, regardless of which time zone the application runs in.

E.g., create `Calendar` instance in GMT time zone and populate its fields:

```
TimeZone gmtTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT" );

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone( gmtTimeZone );
calendar.set( Calendar.YEAR, 1982 );
calendar.set( Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY );
calendar.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23 );
calendar.set( Calendar.HOUR, 1 );
calendar.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 2 );
calendar.set( Calendar.SECOND, 3 );
calendar.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 4 );
```

Retrieve UTC timestamp from calendar:

```
Date utcDate = calendar.getTime();
```

From what I understand, `utcDate` is now the number of milliseconds between `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.000 GMT` and `January 23, 1982, 01:02:03.004 GMT`.
See `Date` Javadocs:

```
    /**
     * Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
     * represented by this <tt>Date</tt> object.
     *
     * @return the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
     *          represented by this date.
     */
```

Create date formatter and set its time zone to GMT too:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" );
dateTimeFormat.setTimeZone( gmtTimeZone );
```

Format date object into string:

```
String stringDate = dateTimeFormat.format( utcDate );
```

Now, when I do:

```
System.out.println( utcDate.getTime() );
System.out.println( stringDate );
```

I get:

```
> 380638923004
> 1982-01-23 13:02:03.004+0000
```

However, what I expected was (note `13` hours vs `01` hours):

```
> 1982-01-23 01:02:03.004+0000
```

I.e., because I set the time to 1 (1am) with `calendar.set( Calendar.HOUR, 1 );`, I expect the time to be 1 (1am) not 13 (1pm).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So instead of 1300 hours, you want 1pm?

Comment: So, according to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), *"H - Hour in day (0-23)"*. Perhaps you should check the docs for a specifier which better meets your requirements

Comment: No, I expected 1am because `calendar.set( Calendar.HOUR, 1 );`

Comment: Now I understand what you meant, thanks @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd' 'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ" );
dateTimeFormat.setTimeZone( gmtTimeZone );
```

This will give you the expected output.

'h' in the date format string will display as hour in am/pm (1-12) according to the JavaDoc for SimpleDateFormat.

EDIT:
Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY should be used to set the hour for a 24-hour clock.

Comment: Spencer, would you mind modifying your answer by removing the point about `h` vs `H` and AM vs PM please? a 24 hour clock is what I wanted, and never specified otherwise. The actual problem was `Calendar.HOUR` vs `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`, as you pointed out in your first edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35304666/642706) by [Spencer Brett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5900672/spencer-brett) says, you should have used `hh` lowercase if you meant [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) rather than 24-hour.

## java.time

When using Java 8 and later, you should avoid these notoriously troublesome old date-time classes (java.util.Date/.Calendar etc.). They have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `Instant`

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

### `OffsetDateTime`

However an `Instant` has limited formatting, and limited ways to instantiate. So let's look at [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) which you can think of as an `Instant` combined with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (a [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)). To specify our offset, we can use the constant [`java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC). To instantiate an `OffsetDateTime` we first build a [date-only](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and a [time-only](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), then combine with an offset.

### Nanosecond Resolution

The java.time classes have [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution. You intended milliseconds in your Question’s example. So we will convert using [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html). You could do the multiplication yourself but that is error-prone. And [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) is self-documenting.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 1982 , 1 , 23 );
long nanoseconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert( 4 , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of( 1 , 2 , 3 , nanoseconds );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( localDate , localTime , ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

### ISO 8601

The java.time classes use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats by default in their `toString` methods. So you need not specify a format as that is close to your desired output. Not quite the same as the standard format includes a `T` in the middle rather than a SPACE.

```
String output = odt.toString();
```

> 1982-01-23T01:02:03.004Z

Either replace the `T` with a SPACE, or search Stack Overflow for many examples of using `DateTimeFormatter` class in java.time.

```
String output = odt.toString().replace( "T" , " " );
```

Comment: Thanks Basil. FYI, it was not `hh` vs `HH` that was my error -- `HH` is a 24hour clock and that is what I wanted. My error was using `Calendar.HOUR` instead of `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`. Thanks for the tip about Java 8.